# OR, XOR Calculation (XOR -> XOR -> OR -> JNZ)

Tags: assembly, x86, xor

I'm trying to solve (as in jump not being taken) the below code but I have the feeling that this is a catch 22.

```
XOR EDX,EDI  (00268725,00000000)
XOR EAX,ECX  (AF51B153, user input)
OR  EDX, EAX (00268725,EAX) 
JNZ some address
```

What is the trick here. I'm trying to get the last OR to 0 but if I input the value that would cancel out to 0 in the last instruction, it obviously messes up during the previous instruction.

- EDI seems to always be 00000000. (but I doubt if it should be)
- EAX always seems to be AF51B153
- EDX always seems to be 00268725

Comment: Maybe it's me, but I don't understand this syntax

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? To get `eax` to equal 0, xor it with itself `xor eax,eax`

Comment: These are 3 instructions that end with a jnz. So xor 1, xor 2, and last an or, followed by a jnz. I need the result of the last OR to be 0.

Comment: Ok so to get 0 out of an OR, both inputs must be 0. So `edi = 0` and `eax = 0`. To make `eax` zero, it must have been equal to `ecx`.

Comment: Harold, sorry. I mistyped the last instruction. It's or EDX,EAX not EDI, EAX

Comment: Your question is unclear.  What you mean by "solve"? You mean determine the values in registers before the first XOR instruction is executed, such that the OR EDX, EAX before the JNZ produces a zero in EDX?   And what do the numbers in parentheses mean?

Comment: Ira, the numbers are the values (see bullet points). The solve = the result of the last OR should be zero so that the jump is not taken.

Comment: If only "user input" is available to be modified, than this can't be resolved. The `XOR EDX,EDI` will keep `edx` set to `00268725`. `00268725` OR `<anything>` will be non-zero value. Check [how OR works](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR).

Comment: @BartDecker `edx` and `edi` should also be equal then.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this. In the code you've shown, the conditional branch will *always* be taken. Why is this so? Well, let's analyze the code:

> ```
> XOR EDX,EDI  (00268725,00000000)
> ```

If I'm reading this correctly, the parenthetical notation to the right specifies the values that will be in the `EDX` and `EDI` registers at the time this line of code is executed. If they are truly both constants, then this instruction seems rather pointless—why XOR by two constant values at run-time, when you can just do it at compile-time and set `EDX` to the result?

Anyway, `00268725 XOR 0` == `00268725`, since any number XOR 0 is that same number.
The truth table for XOR is as follows:

```
|   Input   | Output |
|  A  |  B  |        |
|-----|-----|--------|
|  0  |  0  |   0    |
|  0  |  1  |   1    |
|  1  |  0  |   1    |
|  1  |  1  |   0    |
```

Thus, after this instruction is executed, `EDX` contains `00268725`, which is consistent with your observations.

(I don't know what you mean when you say that you doubt whether `EDI` should contain 0. Either the register contains a defined value, or it receives an unpredictable input value. In the former case, you can analyze the code. In the latter, you can't.)

> ```
> XOR EAX,ECX  (AF51B153, user input)
> ```

Here, `AF51B153` (in `EAX`) will be XORed with the user input (in `ECX`). Since the user input is not a constant value, we can't predict what the result will be, but it doesn't matter once we look at the next instruction…

> ```
> OR  EDX, EAX (00268725,EAX)
> ```

Now, the result of the first instruction (in `EDX`) is ORed with the result of the second instruction (in `EAX`). Here is the truth table for the OR function:

```
|   Input   | Output |
|  A  |  B  |        |
|-----|-----|--------|
|  0  |  0  |   0    |
|  0  |  1  |   1    |
|  1  |  0  |   1    |
|  1  |  1  |   1    |
```

Since we know that the value of `EDX` is `00268725`, it doesn't matter what the value of `EAX` is. There is no value with which you could OR `00268725` to get 0. The only way to get 0 out of an OR function is for both inputs to be 0, and you know that `EDX` is always non-zero.

Thus, the result of this instruction (in `EDX`) is always going to be non-zero, and thus the zero flag (`ZF`) will *never* be set. And that means that `JNZ` will *always* take the branch.

Comment: Thanks for your very elaborated explanation with the graph. This helped me further to look why EDI was always 0. This was the problem!.

Comment: TL:DR summary: This is a pretty normal efficient way to check that two `==` conditions are both true.  But if one of them is false to start with, and you don't control either input to it, you can't change that.  `(00268725 != 00000000) | (AF51B153 != x)` is true for any x.